# Why cant Python request parse TikTok API data?

Tags: python, json, http, python-requests

I am making a Python request using the request library to TikTok. I managed to dig up the URL for their user details (I don't know whether this is legal or not. If it isn't, please let me know). When I try to parse it into json, it raises an exception. Could someone helpme parse/fix this? Here is the code:
Python Code:

```
r1 = requests.get("https://www.tiktok.com/node/share/user/@nike?isUniqueId=true&verifyFp=verify_kb51zknj_GH98fcme_eDuR_4XzM_ATwp_s8TRdCzr8fwi&_signature=KBbp4AAgEBCtR.e4r-y0ZSgWqPAAHbR").json()
print(r1)
```

Output:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 897, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Thanks

Comment: did you try to print the response body before using a JSON decoder? Maybe it's not JSON, but some kind of other encoding. Also, you should check the response headers. To play with this, I'd recommend a GUI tool like Postman.

Comment: @Pac0 what do you mean by printing the result before decoding it?

Comment: something like this : `r = requests.get(url)` and then print `r.text` . Also, `r.headers`, and first of all r.status_code to check if there was an error ot not. See https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/.

Comment: @Pac0 it prints out an empty line. I checked the response headers and it says that the content encoding is in br/Brotli. Could this be pertinent to the issue?

Comment: sorry, I made an edit to my previous comment. What is the `status_code` ?

Comment: @Pac0 The status code was 200, but when printing out the headers, it says that the content length is 0

Comment: ok, strange, because if I copy-paste the url in my browser, I get a full JSON response.

Comment: @Pac0 same. thats. what I dont understand

Comment: @JiříOujezdský could you explain what that means?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you must provide user-agent header, ie

```
headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36',
}

r1 = requests.get("https://www.tiktok.com/node/share/user/@nike?isUniqueId=true&verifyFp=verify_kb51zknj_GH98fcme_eDuR_4XzM_ATwp_s8TRdCzr8fwi&_signature=KBbp4AAgEBCtR.e4r-y0ZSgWqPAAHbR", headers=headers).json()
print(r1)
```

sory I tried to post it as comment, but failed to format the code xD

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain what a user agent is and when I need to use it?

Comment: nice catch! @Serket : a user agent is just a header text that announce "which browser" (== agent) is performing the request. It's easily fakeable, so you can send reqeust "as if it cam from Firefox" or "Safari" etc..

Comment: @Pac0 then why didn't I need to add the user agent when performing this on other links for Instagram, etc.?

Comment: For some reason, the tiktok API performs some filtering on this header. I don't know why, since you can fake it so easily.

Comment: user agent is usually used when browsers do the requests, if u work with API which is expected to be used programmatically then there is usually no demand for that header. Maybe tiktok has some other api than what you posted?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a wrapper in Python that allows you to fetch Users, Videos, Hashtags, Videos by music, etc.
The project can be found here - [TikTokAPI-Python](https://avilash.github.io/TikTokAPI-Python/)

For your problem of fetching a user -

Install

```
pip install PyTikTokAPI
```

Get user

```
from TikTokAPI import TikTokAPI
api = TikTokAPI()
user_obj = api.getUserByName("fcbarcelona")
```

Comment: can you get the user information with that?, like how many follower does he have?

Comment: it would be nice to have the possibility to get the videos by hashtag AND sorted by popularity. Because in this way you download always the same videos